# System.FormatException with ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

I'm using a `ScriptManager` in an ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Since then, an error occurs each time I rebuilt my page (loads the assemblies):

```
[FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) +3624418
   System.Windows.Forms.TypeLibraryTimeStampAttribute..ctor(String timestamp) +49
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs) +0
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs) +46
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent) +529
   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType) +103
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit) +33
   System.Web.UI.AssemblyCache.GetAjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute(Assembly assembly) +76
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.get_DefaultAjaxFrameworkAssembly() +399
   System.Web.UI.ScriptManager..ctor() +26
   ASP.usercontrols_asyncprocessingmonitor_ascx.__BuildControlScriptManager1() in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\UserControls\AsyncProcessingMonitor.ascx:5
   ASP.usercontrols_asyncprocessingmonitor_ascx.__BuildControlTree(usercontrols_asyncprocessingmonitor_ascx __ctrl) in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\UserControls\AsyncProcessingMonitor.ascx:1
   ASP.usercontrols_asyncprocessingmonitor_ascx.FrameworkInitialize() in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\UserControls\AsyncProcessingMonitor.ascx.cs:912307
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +35
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControl(Page page) +14
   ASP.provisioning_default_aspx.__BuildControlasyncProcessingMonitor1() in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\Provisioning\default.aspx:124
   ASP.provisioning_default_aspx.__BuildControlpnlProcessMonitor() in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\Provisioning\default.aspx:123
   ASP.provisioning_default_aspx.__BuildControlForm1() in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\Provisioning\default.aspx:51
   ASP.provisioning_default_aspx.__BuildControlTree(provisioning_default_aspx __ctrl) in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\Provisioning\default.aspx:1
   ASP.provisioning_default_aspx.FrameworkInitialize() in d:\Developpement\Projects\CyberClasse\LNMManager\ManagementConsole\Provisioning\default.aspx.cs:912308
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +78
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +49
   ASP.provisioning_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Users\nba\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\managementconsole\6fc95b25\3fc34eab\App_Web_pm33amsb.2.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +100
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Once I refresh my page, the error disappears. 
I don't understand this error. In many forums, it was about the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly as the source of this error. This assembly was referenced in my WebSite project, but I removed it and the error still occurs.

#### EDIT

This issue was reported [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1581204/4142689.aspx), and [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-and-stylesheetmanager/the-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime.aspx) (but about a custom script manager), for example.

#### EDIT 2

Well. Here is some code of the user control, which is inserted in the asp.net page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" style="width:70%;" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldProcessID" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldRedirectURL" runat="server" Value="" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldRedirect" runat="server" Value="false" />
        <asp:Timer ID="TimerStatusUpdate" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="TimerStatusUpdateTick"></asp:Timer>
        <br/><br/>
        <div align="center"><asp:Image ID="ImageProgressGif" runat="server" ImageUrl="https://cms.unov.org/FullTextSearch/Common/Images/progress.gif" /></div>
        <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%;">Label Text :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelCurrent" runat="server"></asp:Label> / <asp:Label ID="LabelTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </b>
                    <input id="inputpercentage" name="inputpercentage" type="text" runat="server" hidden="true"/>
                    <input type="hidden" runat='server' id="completed" value="" />
                    <br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:label id="LabelExportInfo" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="true" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#6666FF"></asp:label>
                    <asp:linkbutton id="LinkExportInfo" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="true" OnClick="DownloadFile" Font-Size="Small"></asp:linkbutton>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelPasswordChanged" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But, as I said, the reported issue shown by the stack trace and the provided topics is from assemblies (its "TypeLibraryTimeStampAttribute" attribute to be more specific). But, my point, how can I know which assembly is it about ?

Moreover, I've deleted the reference to System.Windows.Form in my project, as suggested in the topics, but no result.

#### EDIT 3

A colleague opened the project on his computer, built it and ran it, without any error. Everything works fine with him. So, definitively, this issue in extern of code. 
I'm like John Locke on his island: Lost.

Any clue ?

Comment: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` the error is more than clear and has nothing to do with the ScriptManager.

Comment: The error is general c# error, just because your page is wrapped inside the scriptManager (practically using xmlHTTPhandler) its showing it as a error in the particular block of the page, logged in console, since its a partial page rendering.

Comment: @walther Thanks for that comment. I know what that means, and don't fit at all with my situation. You are not helping.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva my code does not contain any date parsing (well, in fact, no parser at all, not even in javascript). Moreover, how can you explain the reload that make the error disappears ?

Comment: I updated my question. I provided topics with similar issue.

Comment: Maybe my comment doesn't help because you haven't provided enough information? You've shown only the error stack, but we need to see the actual code to help you. The definition of a ScriptManager is completely useless...

Comment: Now, my point seems "less useless", isn't it ? I've tried without code in my updatepanel, without JS, the error still occurs. Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours to resolve this issue, I've found the reason.

It is an assembly, that I need in my project, AxAcroPDFLib.dll (Migradoc that needs AcroPDFLib.dll and generates AxAcroPDFLib.dll). It has an attribute with a bad format date. 
[This guy](http://forums.asp.net/t/1678544.aspx/1?Error%20in%20ScriptManager%20constructor) had the same issue than me.

But I can't unuse Migradoc, so my problem is still on, but now, I know what is exactly the error, and why it occurs.

### EDIT: problem solved

Problem solved, partially.
I cleaned the assemblies that my project needed. Two of the PDFSharp dll were useless, so I removed the references, deleted all the bin folders, and rebuild my solution. 
And TADAAAAA. The AxAcroPDFLib.dll has disappeared, the error does not come back.